# Creating a Auto Generation ID with Prefix in MySQL Without Using Trigger

Tags: sql, mysql, database, mysql-workbench

Creating a Auto Generation ID with Prefix in MySQL Without Using Trigger
I need Creating a Employee Id with Prefix and Without Using Trigger in MySQL.

Comment: Do this on the client side.

Answer (score 2):

To create an auto-generated employee ID with a prefix in MySQL without using triggers, you can follow one of the approaches below:

1. Using AUTO_INCREMENT

---

You can use the AUTO_INCREMENT feature in MySQL to automatically generate unique IDs for your employees.

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    employee_prefix VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    employee_number INT
);

-- Insert a row (ID will be automatically generated)
INSERT INTO employees (employee_prefix) VALUES ('EMP');

-- Get the generated ID
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

2. Computed Column

---

You can create a computed column that combines the prefix and an auto-incremented value.

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    employee_number INT,
    employee_id AS CONCAT('EMP', LPAD(employee_number, 5, '0')) PERSISTENT
);

-- Insert a row (ID will be automatically generated)
INSERT INTO employees (employee_number) VALUES (1);

-- Get the generated employee ID
SELECT employee_id FROM employees WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Choose the approach that best fits your requirements, and adjust the table and column names as needed. Remember to replace 'EMP' with your desired prefix.

Comment: Thank You . But this code not working on MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Ok what error does the MySQL show? is there any syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

The first paradigm looks fine to me. On the second one i think, that's not a correct syntax for MySQL.

However to use generated columns, you can choose between two opportunities: Virtual / Stored.

[MySQL : 15.1.20.8 CREATE TABLE and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

My read is, the example (on using the above described example, part 2) will use stored columns:

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employee_number` INT NULL,
  `employee_id` VARCHAR(8) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT('EMP', LPAD(employee_number, 5, '0'))) STORED,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

INSERT INTO `employees` (`employee_number`) VALUES ('1516');

select * from employees;

+----+-----------------+-------------+
| id | employee_number | employee_id |
+----+-----------------+-------------+
|  1 |            1516 | EMP01516    |
+----+-----------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

This is a very simple example so far. For the further development, i strongly recommend to check (for your intention) the datatypes and boundaries.